# Cannot convert Boost path iterators to strings

Tags: c++, boost, stl, compiler-errors, boost-filesystem

I'm attempting to get the following code from [nmdepend](https://github.com/epronk/nmdepend) to compile

```
const std::string Bfd::packageName(const fs::path& path, int packageLevel)
{
  fs::path::iterator p = path.end();
  --p;

  for(int i = 0; i < packageLevel; ++i)
      --p;

  return *p;
}
```

However it is generating the following compiler error

```
/Users/nick/Software/nmdepend/src/Bfd.cpp: In static member function ‘static const std::string Bfd::packageName(const boost::filesystem3::path&, int)’:
/Users/nick/Software/nmdepend/src/Bfd.cpp:27: error: conversion from ‘const boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘const std::string’ requested
```

How should this code be modified so that a string is returned yet the manipulation that is being attempted by using an iterator is maintained?

Comment: shouldn't it be "return (*p).string();"  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` is not implicitly convertible to string.  This should work though:

```
return p->string();
```

Comment: Or maybe p->native().  Looks like they have change this a lot.  OP, read through http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html

Comment: @Duck: The type returned by that will vary with the environment.  It would return `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` on Windows, and `std::basic_string<char>` on POSIX systems.  The `string` function does the conversions necessary to get it to `std::string`.